# не выводит дату на русском или укр языках

Tags: javascript

использую библиотеку moment.js
выводит так Tuesday, June 28 2016, 11:34:04
а хотелось бы чтобы не на англ.

```
var now = moment();
moment.locale('ru');
//moment.lang('ru'); // так тоже ничего не дает
console.log(now.format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
```

пробовал подключать как min версию так и moment-with-locales.js
результата нет. Нужна ваша помощь.

Answer (score 3):

```
moment.lang("ru").format('LLL');
```

Начиная с версии 2.8 нужно использовать

```
moment.locale("ru").format('LLL');
```

Comment: увы, но не помогло((

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае вот так:

```
var now = moment();
console.log(now.locale("ru").format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/